# How to properly configure CMake Tools in VsCode on MacOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I configure CMake Tools extension on Windows or Linux, the end result looks something like this:
[image: VsCode CMake tools on Windows]

This allows the user to quickly switch build type and executables (targets) to build, debug or run. It also allows you to quickly switch between different compilers (not that I use this often but it is nevertheless neat).

On MacOS, however, the situation is different. No matter how I try and which How-To articles I follow I can't get that bottom pannel to display that information:
[image: VsCode CMake Tools on macOS]

On all of the systems I have C++ compilers, Cmake and VsCode installed. I also have VsCode [CMake](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=twxs.cmake) and [Cmake Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) extensions installed in VsCode and I assumed it should be enough for MacOS too but I clearly was wrong.

On MacOS I have cloned my project, opened it with VsCode, configured it via CMake extension, and selected a kit (compiler) but the bottom ribbon still looks the same and I don't understand how to make CMake-Tools-specific functionality appear. I can press `cmd+shift+P`, start typing "Cmake:..." and receive the list of commands to control the CMake flow but it is less convenient than simply having a ribbon at the bottom of the screen which allows me to change the configuration in only a few clicks.

Does someone know what am I missing here?

I have MacBook Pro Apple M1 13-inch 2020 with macOS Ventura 13.4.1

Don't suggest using XCode for development on macOS, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

Go to the settings and search for "`@ext:ms-vscode.cmake-tools status`". Look for an option called `Cmake: Use Project Status View` uncheck it.

Or you can go to `settings.json` and add the following line:

```
    "cmake.useProjectStatusView": false,
```

After making this change your status bar on the bottom of your screen should look something like this:
[image]